# Load constants from outside war file

Tags: spring

I am working spring mvc project in that constants are different from development environment and production environment.how to provide constants file outside war in spring or any alternative way to provide constants depending on environment

Answer (score 1):

If the constant depends on the Environment, then I prefer to put them in the Application Server Context.

For example if you put this snippet in the tomcat `context.xml` (or a application specific context file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    ...
    <Parameter name="myConfig" value="123" override="false" />
</Context>
```

Then you can use the parameter `myConfig` in Spring like any other configuration parameter.

```
<bean class="Demo">
   <property name="config" value="${myConfig}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: i am new to spring framework could please provide example for this

Comment: @Aswan: see my extended answer

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using Container's Context, since it couples your webapp to specific container provider (contexts params are not standarized, are they?).

What I'm using for such scenarios is the following solution:

1. Define Property Placeholder for Spring (see [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html))
2. Create file with all necessary config (or multiple files), for instance: `config.properties`
3. Define and export external environment variable and point it to some config directory, for instance: `export MY_CONFIG=/usr/share/myapp`. **Do that on both environments** (actuall directory might change). But your config in this directory.
4. Use `$(env.MY_CONFIG}` in property placeholder, to load properties in Spring.

That way you will have two different config settings for development and live environments. Simple, but powerful, since you can have this config in CVS or even use some overloading of resources to make it even more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`s (docs)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) for this. Customized versions can resolve property files based on a variety of things, like server and/or user name, and/or command-line java options through `-Doption.foo.bar=xxx` switches.

I prefer this over context variables for several reasons, mainly to (a) keep configuration changes server-neutral, and (b)  allow switching between configurations "on-demand" without server intervention.